# Render gridview as <div> instead of table

Tags: jquery, html, css, gridview

[image]

I am looking for some code snippet which will render a gridview into `<div>` 
instead of table.
Anyone can help me on this?

I need to draw a graph like the one I have attached and need some features like select the graph area with mouse and provide copy paste operation.

Comment: Why? What's your problem with `<table>` ?

Comment: If you explain us the purpose of that we will be able to help you better. Cheers

Comment: I don't think such thing is possible, since `GridView` is meant to show tabular data. If you want to show things your way, you'll also have to use your own control or just `Literal` and build the raw HTML yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use the **ListView control** introduced along with DotNet framework 3.5.

The **ListView is a template driven control which means that it will not render anything by default**. By default, the developer must completely specify the HTML he/she wants to render in the form of templates (**should specify the HTML that should be rendered within the LayoutTemplate** ).

See the code project url below to get implementation details..

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/CompleteListView.aspx

Also refer the following msdn video,

http://www.asp.net/aspnet-35/videos/the-listview-control

**UPDATE:** Since your project is using DotNet Framework 2.0 you should use a Repeater server control to acheive this

The Repeater control has no built-in layout or styles; you must explicitly declare all HTML layout, formatting, and style tags within the control's templates.

But paging,sorting etc will be a bit difficult using Repeater. The ListView is an updated version of Repeater with the mentioned functionalities as well..

Hope this helps you..

Comment: The project is in DotNet 2.0.

Comment: @gvLearner, Then you should go for a Repeater control. See i've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your CustomGridView which inherits from GridView, and there, you can override Render method to loop through rows and generate any type of HTML you want. But the best way is to use ListView as @Harun said.